# How do I get delegated(Assign to someone else) signer information from docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have enable 'Assign to Someone Else' option using DocuSign REST (signer can perform action of assigning envelope to other signer).
Is there any way to get delegated/newly assign signer information using DocuSign REST?

I am able to get information by using audit logs API `envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events` but it's very difficult to capture information for multiple delegation so is there any direct way or API to get delegated recipient information.

Answer (score 0):

So Signer A delegates to B who delegates to C, and you want to know that this has occurred?

Yes, I think the `audit_events` would be a primary technique. You could also use Connect or eventNotification to be notified when the envelope was delivered to A, then B, then C. -- But you will need to test this idea to see if you receive the individual Recipient.Delivery events.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a "Declined" RecipientEvent when the envelope is initially sent you will get a notification of this through a webhook.  If Signer B delegates to signer C, you will get a single notification which will then contain both signers.  Signer B will have a status of "Declined" and Signer C will have a status of "Sent".